# How to handle #(hash) character in SEO friendly url?

Tags: php, url, codeigniter, seo

How do you bypass the default behaviour if #(hash) which is to go to a specific part of a page? The problem that I have is that the # character is a part of the SEO friendly url which is a title and the #(hash) is part of the content (i.e. like with C#). I can't retrieve the whole string and I only get the characters before the #.

Example:

```
www.domain.com/C#-programming-book
```

in this example I only get 'C' and not the '-programming-book' part. I am not using any javascript at the moment and would like to only use a PHP solution for this.

Before anyone suggests that I used url encoding, the criteria for the seo friendly url is that it should be human readable and easily remembered. So converting the hash to '%23' does not pass the criteria.

Is there no way around it?

Comment: Yes I noticed that too but I was thinking if there is any other alternative solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#` is part of the defined way URLs work which you can't change. The browser will strip off the `#` and any text after it before making a request. Once it gets the response it will then search the page for the element with the `#` name.

Do what most people do and change it to the word "sharp". i.e. "csharp"

Answer (score 1):

`#` characters have special meaning in URLs have need to be encoded as `%23` if they are to appear as data.